# Trying to generate a XML file on save_post

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

I'm trying to update an XML site map whenever a page, post, or CPT is updated.

For troubleshooting purposes, my code is just this - to generate a random number in a short XML file:

```
function xml($post_id){

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->encoding = 'utf-8';
    $dom->xmlVersion = '1.0';
    $dom->formatOutput = true;

        $xml_file_name = 'sitemap.xml';
    $root = $dom->createElement('sitemapindex');
        $root->setAttribute('rand', rand(100,999));

    $dom->appendChild($root);
        $dom->save($xml_file_name);

}
add_action('save_post','xml');
```

This does not work. However if I change the hook from 'save_post' to 'init', this function DOES work - although obviously when I visit the site, and not when a post is saved.

What's the issue with 'save_post', and what should I do to get it working?

Comment: Whenever I'm working on a WordPress hook issue, the first thing I do is make sure the hook is firing for me in the first place. So don't do anything complex, just throw a `die('Here');` into the hook, and if you get that, then you know the hook is firing at least.